# Simple Java Solitaire / Patience card game

Tags: java, game, playing-cards

I made a simple Patience/Solitaire card game. The cards don't use images but JLabels and JPanels. The game is finished when all cards are on their suit piles.

Card movement:

- mousePressed : card -> TOP (suit pile).
- mouseDragged : card(s) -> COLUMN.

I would like some feedback on my code.

```
package patience;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Patience extends JFrame {
    final public static Dimension CARD_SIZE = new Dimension(52, 69);
    final public static int CARD_CLOSED = CARD_SIZE.height / 6, CARD_OPEN = CARD_SIZE.height / 3;
    final public static String SUIT[] = {"\u2660", "\u2665", "\u2663", "\u2666"},  ACE = "A", KING = "K";
    final public static Object[] RANK = {ACE, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", KING};
    private Game game = new Game();
   
    Patience() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new Color(-16726016));
        setResizable(false);
        setContentPane(game);
        setSize(402, 522);
        setVisible(true);
        JButton newGame = new JButton("\u21bb");      
        newGame.setBorder(null);
        newGame.setFocusable(false);
        newGame.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        newGame.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, CARD_SIZE.height / 2));
        newGame.addActionListener(e -> {
            game = new Game();
            setContentPane(game);
            revalidate();
            game.STOCK.requestFocus();
        });
        getLayeredPane().add(newGame).setBounds(10, 440, 40, 40);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Patience().setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    
}
```

```
package patience;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Card extends JPanel {
    final private JPanel FRONT = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    final public Color COLOR;
    final public String SUIT;
    final public Object RANK;
    
    Card(String suit, Object rank) {
        super(null);
        COLOR = new Color[] {Color.black, Color.red}[Arrays.asList(Patience.SUIT).indexOf(suit) % 2];
        SUIT = suit;
        RANK = rank;
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white, 2));
        setBackground(Color.blue);
        setSize(Patience.CARD_SIZE);
        JLabel left = new JLabel("" + rank), right = new JLabel(suit), south = new JLabel(suit, JLabel.CENTER);
        left.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 25));
        left.setForeground(COLOR);
        left.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        left.add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);
        right.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 22));
        right.setForeground(COLOR);
        south.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 36));
        south.setForeground(COLOR);
        FRONT.add(left, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        FRONT.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        FRONT.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));
        FRONT.setBackground(Color.white);
        FRONT.setSize(getSize());
        add(FRONT).setVisible(false);
    }
    
    public boolean isOpen() {
        return FRONT.isVisible();
    }
    
    public void flip() {
        FRONT.setVisible(!FRONT.isVisible());
    }
    
}
```

```
package patience;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ContainerAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ContainerEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JLayeredPane {
    final public JButton STOCK = new JButton();
    final private JPanel OPEN = new JPanel(null), COLUMN[] = new JPanel[7];
    final private JLabel[] TOP = new JLabel[Patience.SUIT.length];
    
    Game() {
        STOCK.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        STOCK.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.darkGray, 2));
        STOCK.setLayout(null);
        STOCK.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (STOCK.getComponentCount() > 0) {
                ((Card) OPEN.add(STOCK.getComponent(0), 0)).flip();
            } else if (OPEN.getComponentCount() > 0) {
                for (Component card : OPEN.getComponents()) {
                    ((Card) STOCK.add(card, 0)).flip();
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
        add(STOCK).setBounds(10, 10, Patience.CARD_SIZE.width, Patience.CARD_SIZE.height);

        for (String suit : Patience.SUIT) {
            for (Object rank : Patience.RANK) {
                STOCK.add(new Card(suit, rank), (int) (Math.random() * (STOCK.getComponentCount() + 1)));
            }
        }

        OPEN.setOpaque(false);
        add(OPEN).setBounds(STOCK.getX() + STOCK.getWidth() + 2, STOCK.getY(), Patience.CARD_SIZE.width, Patience.CARD_SIZE.height);

        for (int i = 0; i < TOP.length; i++) {
            TOP[i] = new JLabel(new String[] {"\u2664", "\u2661", "\u2667", "\u2662"}[i], JLabel.CENTER);
            TOP[i].setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, Patience.CARD_SIZE.height / 2));
            add(TOP[i]).setBounds(STOCK.getX() + (3 + i) * (OPEN.getX() - STOCK.getX()), STOCK.getY(), Patience.CARD_SIZE.width, Patience.CARD_SIZE.height);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < COLUMN.length; i++) {
            COLUMN[i] = new JPanel(null);
            COLUMN[i].setOpaque(false);
            COLUMN[i].addContainerListener(new ContainerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent e) {
                    if (e.getContainer().getComponentCount() > 1) {
                        e.getChild().setLocation(0, e.getContainer().getComponent(1).getY() + new int[] {Patience.CARD_CLOSED, Patience.CARD_OPEN}[Boolean.compare(((Card) e.getContainer().getComponent(1)).isOpen(), false)]);
                    }
                }
            });
            add(COLUMN[i]).setBounds(STOCK.getX() + i * (OPEN.getX() - STOCK.getX()), STOCK.getY() + STOCK.getHeight() + STOCK.getY(), Patience.CARD_SIZE.width, i * Patience.CARD_CLOSED + 11 * Patience.CARD_OPEN + Patience.CARD_SIZE.height);
            for (int row = 0; row <= i; row++) {
                COLUMN[i].add(STOCK.getComponent(0), 0);
            }
            ((Card) COLUMN[i].getComponent(0)).flip();
        }

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                try {
                    Container pressed = (Container) getComponentAt(e.getPoint());
                    if (getLayer(pressed) == 0) {
                        Card card = (Card) pressed.getComponentAt(pressed.getMousePosition());
                        if (card.isOpen()) {
                            JPanel dragged = new JPanel(null);
                            dragged.setBounds(pressed.getX(), pressed.getY() + card.getY(), pressed.getWidth(), pressed.getComponent(0).getY() + pressed.getComponent(0).getHeight() - card.getY());
                            for (int i = pressed.getComponentZOrder(card), y = 0; i >= 0; i--, y += Patience.CARD_OPEN) {
                                dragged.add(pressed.getComponent(i), 0).setLocation(0, y);
                            }
                            MouseMotionAdapter mma = new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                                int x = dragged.getX() - e.getX(), y = dragged.getY() - e.getY();
                                @Override
                                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                                    dragged.setLocation(Math.max(0, Math.min(e.getX() + x, getWidth() - dragged.getWidth())), Math.max(0, Math.min(e.getY() + y, getHeight() - dragged.getHeight())));
                                }
                            };
                            add(dragged, new Integer(1));
                            addMouseMotionListener(mma);
                            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                                Container next = pressed;
                                @Override
                                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                                    removeMouseListener(this);
                                    removeMouseMotionListener(mma);
                                    remove(dragged);
                                    Container released = (Container) getComponentAt(e.getPoint());
                                    if (released == pressed) {
                                        JLabel suit = TOP[Arrays.asList(Patience.SUIT).indexOf(card.SUIT)];
                                        if (card == dragged.getComponent(0) && card.RANK == Patience.RANK[suit.getComponentCount()]) {
                                            next = suit;
                                        }
                                    } else if (Arrays.asList(COLUMN).contains(released) && card.RANK != Patience.ACE) {
                                        if (card.RANK == Patience.KING) {
                                            if (released.getComponentCount() == 0) {
                                                next = released;
                                            }
                                        } else if (released.getComponentCount() >= 1) {
                                            Card last = (Card) released.getComponent(0);
                                            if (last.isOpen() && last.COLOR != card.COLOR && last.RANK == Patience.RANK[Arrays.asList(Patience.RANK).indexOf(card.RANK) + 1]) {
                                                next = released;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    for (int i = dragged.getComponentZOrder(card); i >= 0; i--) {
                                        next.add(dragged.getComponent(i), 0);
                                    }
                                    if (TOP[0].getComponentCount() == Patience.RANK.length && TOP[1].getComponentCount() == Patience.RANK.length && TOP[2].getComponentCount() == Patience.RANK.length && TOP[3].getComponentCount() == Patience.RANK.length) {
                                        time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) / 1000;
                                        JLabel completed = new JLabel((time / 60) + " min " + (time % 60) + " sec", JLabel.CENTER);
                                        completed.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, Patience.CARD_SIZE.height / 3));
                                        completed.setSize(getSize());
                                        add(completed, new Integer(1));
                                    }
                                    repaint();
                                }
                            });
                        } else if (card == pressed.getComponent(0)) {
                            card.flip();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) { }
            }
        });
    }
    
}
```

Comment: i would really LOVE to see a follow up question on your improvement (heart)

Answer (score 1):

### [separation of concerns](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-2-orange/#Separation_of_Concerns_SoC) / [MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444431/what-is-difference-between-mvc-mvp-mvvm-design-pattern-in-terms-of-coding-c-s) / [Single responsibility](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-2-orange/#Single_Responsibility_Principle_SRP)

you mix your Model and your presentation, you should try to apply to the well known pattern MVC / MVVP / ...

**→ violation of these lead to bloated classes**

### [iosp](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-1-red/#Integration_Operation_Segregation_Principle_IOSP)

you mix integration methods with operation methods.

**→ violation of iosp these leads to bloated methods**

### minor issue: proper use of enum

`final public static Object[] RANK = {ACE, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", KING};`

use [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead

### summary: use [OOP](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-oriented-analysis-and-design/)

you should use a more object orientated programming (using oo analysis & oo design)

**all your code is pressed into three classes - OMG**